# PHP: replace all characters in a string with spaces

Tags: php, html, regex

How do I replace all characters in a string with spaces in PHP?

```
"granny" -> "      "
```

OR, which is a better question, 
how do I know the x coordinate of a symbol echoed out on an HTML page to begin the next line right under it???

```
file.txt 7: Back To Black
            By Killian
```

(not exactly monotype, but that'll work too, although that'll be not 100% satisfactory)

Comment: Need an example input and output.

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine how those two questions are related.

Comment: Could you explain better your question?

Comment: If by `character` you mean any symbol in the string, you basically could do this: `$spaces = str_repeat(' ', str_len('Your string goes here'));`

Comment: Updated. OK, GolezTrol, that seems great

Comment: Looking at your updated question.  If this is HTML output, I think it's better to have one element containing the filename, and an element next to it containing the two lines of text. The second element could have a break between the lines.

Comment: The traditional way to do this is with `<table>`. There may be other, more modern approaches with DIVs and CSS. But using spaces is almost certainly not right (you'd at least need to use `&nbsp;`).

Comment: strlen() worked. GolezTrol, exactly how I thought it out. Barmar, thank you! Haven't thought about tables, perfect!

Comment: Using `&nbsp;` as barmar said, would also need the font to be mono-spaced variant. Or if its inside a `<pre>` tag... or a css element with `white-space: pre;`. Or heck, is this going into a text only email? Or a text file for logging... or... lol.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a clear case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since your seemingly different questions are both about attempts at a solution for a single problem: laying out text.

If by character you mean any symbol in the string, you basically could do this:

```
$spaces = str_repeat(' ', str_len('Your string goes here'));
```

This basically uses two functions, [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to repeat a string (in this case a single space) a given number of times. That number is the length of your actual string, to be determined using [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

But this solution will work only when you have a monospaced font and good control over the output. It could be a workable solution for a console...

For website output, however, you would probably want to have a more styled layout. You could achieve this, for instance, by having two elements that are styled as inline-blocks, table cells, or using the powerful [CSS flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Below just an example of how it might look with html elements that describe the structure of the data, and CSS to declare how they are positioned.

```css
.book {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.filename {
  padding-right: 10px;
  
}
.title::after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
}

.author::before {
  content: 'by ';
}
```

```html
<section class="book">
  <div class="filename">File1.txt</div>
  <div class="description">
    <span class="title">Title</span>
    <span class="author">Author</span>
  </div>
<section>
```

Comment: More than perfect!